# How to install winxp through lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

Is there a way to make windows xp bootable pendrive in ubuntu.

I have seen winusb but it seems that it only supports winvista and win7.

Comment: I think that question is for win 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dd` command. If you have an iso image of the cdrom you can use:

```
dd if=/path/to/iso/winxp.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

or is you have a windows XP CD-ROM you can use:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

**Note:** The `/dev/sdc` disk is just an example. You have to find out which drive is your pendrive. You can use either `df` or `lsblk` commands. Otherwise you might **overwrite hard drive** with important data.